# Convergence in the narrow topology of measures and strongly converge for signed measures

Tags: measure-theory, limits-and-convergence

We say that a sequence $(\mu_{n})$ of measures in $M_{b}(Q)$ converges **tightly** (or, equivalently, in the narrow topology of measures) to a measure $\mu$ in $M_{b}(Q)$ if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{Q}\varphi d\mu_{n} \to \int_{Q}\varphi d\mu\quad (1.1)$$
for every $\varphi\in C_{b}(Q)$. If (1.1) holds only for all the continuous functions $\varphi$ with compact support in $Q$ (i.e., $\varphi\in C_{c}(Q))$, then we have the usual weak–* convergence in $M_{b}(Q)$. What is  the relation between **tight** and strong convergence? The two definitions are equivalent for nonnegative measures, but why not for general signed measures (a counter-example))?

Comment: What are your assumptions? Are $\mu_n$ bounded? Is $Q$ the space of rationals? Please be more precise.

Comment: If $Q$ is just some space, take $Q = \mathbb{N}$ and let $\mu_n$ be a point mass at $n$.  This sequence converges in weak-* to the zero measure, but diverges in the narrow topology (take $\varphi(n) = (-1)^n$).

Comment: $Q$ is the parabolic space $(0,T)\times\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded space of $R^{N}$.

Comment: Does parabolic mean product? And still my question: Are the $\mu_n$ bounded? $M_b$ seems to indicate boundedness.

Comment: Further, since $\Omega$ is a bounded subset (?) of $\mathbb{R}^N$, I think that here $N$ is finite. Correct? To answer your question we must know: Is $\Omega$ a closed (hence compact subset) or open or ... subset?

Comment: The assumptions are: $Q=(0,T)\times\Omega$ with $\Omega$ is a bounded open set of $R^{N}$ with Lipschitz boundary $\partial\Omega$ and $\mu_{n}$ is a sequence of measures (not necessarily bounded) which converges to $\mu$ in the narrow topology of measures where $\mu$ is a singular measure decomposed as $\mu_{s}^{+}-\mu_{s}^{-}$.

Comment: Sorry, if these measures are signed, how do you define $\int 1 d\mu$?

Comment: Okay, so modify my example appropriately: since $Q$ is not closed, take a sequence $(t_n, x_n)$ of distinct points of $Q$ that converge to some point $(t,x)$ which is not in $Q$.  For instance, $(t_n, x_n) = (1/n, x_0)$ would do.  Then the sequence of point masses $\mu_n = \delta_{(t_n, x_n)}$ converge in weak-* to the zero measure and diverge in the narrow topology (by the Tietze extension theorem there is a bounded continuous function $\varphi$ with $\varphi(t_n, x_n) = (-1)^n$).

Comment: @DieterKadelka: The definition of a signed measure typically requires that at least one of $\mu^+, \mu^-$ is finite, so that the integral of a constant is well defined (but could be either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$).

Comment: Remark: It is easy to check that measures that vanish tightly actually strongly converge to zero for diffuse measures (absolutely continuous measures), but at least for (nonnegative) singular (signed) measures. In Wikipidia: the strong convergence of measures is defined by : a sequence $\mu_{n}$ is said to converge strongly to a limit $\mu$ if $\lim _{{n\to \infty }}\mu _{n}(A)=\mu (A)$ for every set $A\in \mathcal{F}$. Do you know a parabolic sequences of singular measures which converges tightly and don't converges strongly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You claim that weak (i.e. tight) and strong convergence are equivalent for non-negative measures, but this is false: take $Q = (0,T) \times (-1,1)$, let $t \in (0,T)$ and let $\mu_n$ be the Dirac measure concentrated at $(t, \frac 1 n)$ and $\mu$ be the Dirac measure concentrated at $(t,0)$. If $\varphi \in C_b (Q)$ then, since $\varphi$ is continuous,

$$\int _Q \varphi \ \mathrm d \mu_n = \varphi \left( t, \frac 1 n \right) \to \varphi (t,0) = \int _Q \varphi \ \mathrm d \mu$$

so that $\mu_n \to \mu$ tightly.

On the other hand, $\{(t,0)\}$ is measurable, and

$$\mu_n \big( \{(t, 0)\} \big) = 0 \not\to 1 = \mu \big( \{(t, 0)\} \big)$$

which shows that $\mu_n \not\to \mu$ strongly.